# Cannot copy files with Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, windows-10

I created a GPO and wanted to use the Group Policy Management to copy files to another computers.

**(Computer Configuration > Preferences > Windows setting >Files)**

```
Action: Create
Source File: \\servername\abc\test.txt
Destination File: C:\abc\test.txt
```

However, no file is copied. Then, using the event viewer to view the log but the log had not any errors. So, I thought the problem is related to permission issue. [I tried to create everyone in the abc folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZKNL.png) [The share folder also allowed everyone to access.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SvkS.png) Using file copy with GPO still not works.

Comment: You can check if the GPO is applied on the target computer with the following command (as admin) `gpresult /h c:\temp\report.html /s system`. Can you see your GPO in the list ?

Comment: @Swisstone Yes, I can see the GPO in the list.

Comment: Add the following registry key/values on the target computer, then `gpupdate`, and see what errors are in the log file:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Group Policy\{7150F9BF-48AD-4da4-A49C-29EF4A8369BA}` => `LogLevel` (Type: DWORD, Value: 3) and `TraceLevel` (Type: DWORD, Value: 2) and `TraceFilePathMachine` (Type: REG_SZ, Value: c:\temp\GPPFileTrace.log for example)

Comment: @Swisstone Thank u so much. I found the errors from the log file. The error is the network path not found. So, I found that the source file path typo. It should type the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "Computer Configuration" can't copy files. Even if a PC account has full access to both directories.

Only "User Configuration" works fine